# Count how many attributes have a word as a substring of longer text value

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, count

For example, if I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
id    title    
1     assistant
2     chief executive officer
3     director
4     chief operations officer
5     assistant manager
6     producer
```

If I wanted to find how many `title` have the word **assistant** in them, the result should be `2`. If I wanted to find how many `title` have **chief** in them, the result should be `2` as well.

Is there a fast way to do this using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
print (df.title.str.count('chief'))
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
Name: title, dtype: int64

print (df.title.str.count('chief').sum())
2

print (df.title.str.count('assistant').sum())
2
```